# Material-UI component variants are not being applied

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui in a react app. Here's the code in question (I'll include the redux stuff just in case):

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button variant="contained" href="#constrained-buttons">
                    Link
                </Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { alert } = state;
    return {
        alert
    };
}

const connectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
export { connectedApp as App };
```

I'm using https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/ as a guide. Here's what shows up:

[image]

This is all that shows up. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have variant `constrained`, but do you mean `contained`?

Comment: Thanks @Tholle, that's a typo in my question (but not my code). Edited.

Comment: Have you tried multiple browsers?

Comment: Thanks @MadisonCourto! I've tried both Chrome and Edge with the same results.

Comment: I have replicated the code in codesandbox and have the expected results.  What do you see in your browser?  https://codesandbox.io/s/pyy5wq809j

Comment: Do you have css overriding styles for `a` tag?

Comment: It looks fine, are you able to view https://codesandbox.io/s/pyy5wq809j correctly?